# How to write a PL/SQL code to calculate the years of experience for the employees whose numbers are 7788 and 7782

Tags: sql, database, xcode, oracle, plsql

Write a PL/SQL code to calculate the years of experience for the employees whose
numbers are 7788 and 7782

then print the information for the employee who has the
oldest experience.

- Write the code using the Reference %ROWTYPE.
- Use the appropriate functions for date and numbers to calculate the experience.
- Print the result as shown below:

```
The Oldest Employee Is: CLARK
His Years of Experience: 38
```

This is my answer dunno what's wrong or if there's any

```
DECLARE 
    EmpInfo emp%ROWTYPE; 
    MaxEx number :=0; 
    EmployeeName emp.ename%TYPE; 
    ExNumber number; 
cursor oldex is select * from emp where EMP.EMPNO = 7788 or EMP.EMPNO = 7782 ; 
BEGIN OPEN oldex; 
    LOOP FETCH oldex into EmpInfo; 
    EXIT WHEN oldex%notfound; 
    ExNumber := (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) - TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(EmpInfo.hiredate,'YYYY'))); 
    if ExNumber > MaxEx then MaxEx := ExNumber; 
    EmployeeName := EmpInfo.ename; 
END IF; 
END LOOP;
 
dbms_output.put_line('The oldest employee is: '|| EmployeeName); 
dbms_output.put_line('His year experiance is: '|| MaxEx); 
CLOSE oldex; 
END;
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? You are supposed to show your effort at solving the problem by yourself.

Comment: @GMB I just posted my answer

Comment: OK, this should be an edit to your question rather than an answer. I copied (and formatted) your code inside your question, you can remove your answer. You should also tell us what is wrong with your current code. Are you getting an error (please share the error message), or maybe wrong results (what is wrong)?

Comment: first time posting a question. 
And now tried to run the code again didn't give me any errors,

Thank you.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you, It seems I'm not getting any errors for now

Comment: Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the Question/Answer format is suppose to work. If you're not getting any errors and your code is working fine, this isn't really a Question.

Comment: If there isn't really a Question, there can no be Answer, right?

Comment: Am I correct that your problem is you are note seeing any output so you can't debug ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing results, probably because you're not setting serveroutput. Example:

```
 begin
   dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
 end;
 /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Where did that string go ? Well, it is in the buffer and you need to tell your sql client to check what is in the buffer and print it. Like this:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
end;
/

hello world


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Use this for your block to see your output. I'll leave it up to you to debug your code.